# Steps for creating a facebook app that will allow our users to add the app as a tab on their page, provide an id and fetch the data from our server

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I've had a hard time finding anything like what I'm trying to accomplish, seems as though FB updates their way of doing things every 6 months.  The documentation I have found is hard to follow and I'm sure this can't be too hard.  Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. We operate a SaaS (in simple terms:) need to allow the user to provide a Form ID and return them a form via iFrame
2. Product management wants to be able to provide our customers with an app on Facebook where they would need to only add in their Form ID + Title, don't care about actual authentication with our product, just an ID to fetch.
3. The app would show up as a tab on their Facebook Page (and/or profile?) with the title of the tab showing what they entered and an iframe with the formId as the parameter to the source.. ie: the contents of that page tab would be a loaded iFrame: <iframe src="http://gotomyserver.com/fetch?FormId=123">
4. The idea is that our customers customers will see this form loaded up if they click on that tab on the page.

This doesn't seem like it should be overly complicated, however I'm having a lot of trouble finding information / understanding the documentation, or maybe I'm approaching it in the wrong manner?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I had found the documentation but really wasn't following it well with what I was trying to do.  Looked it over again after a nights sleep and opted for a new page tab url with a link to our forms.  Created some tutorials for our users to be able to do this themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible at least because the same app can't have different titles depending on the page it is shown.

I would recommend you to make web application that serves the forms. Creating app everytime a user wants takes 5 minute. You will just need to insert in page tab url the corresponding address: http://gotomyserver.com/fetch?FormId=123 and set the title. Even your clients can do that by themselves.
Displaying an app to a facebook page takes an url copy/paste.

Comment: This is what I ended up going with, about a 12 step tutorial for users to add a Page Tab which would feed our form into their page.